# GPX File does not load iOS Xcode

Tags: xcode

Xcode ver.9.4.1へ GPXファイルを追加したいのですが、`Debug〜Simulate Location`のあとAdd GPX File to Projectがグレー字のままで進めません。
お忙しいところすみませんがご教示願います。

Comment: 「Debug〜Simulate Locationのあと」と言うのが一体何をしたのかよくわからないのですが? 特定の操作がうまくできないと言うのであれば、いったいどんな操作をしたのかが具体的にわかるように説明してください。

Comment: なお、タイトルがエラーメッセージをコピーしたものと言うわけでも無いのに英語になっていますが、こちらは日本語でのQ&Aを扱うサイトなので、タイトルも日本語にしてください。ご自身の投稿は「編集」からタイトル・本文とも編集できます。

Comment: 英語版SOに同じタイトルの質問がありますので参考までに - https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428073/2322778

Comment: cubickさま☆ お教えくださった英語版サイトを見ました。
なんと！私と ほぼ同状況ですので手助けになりそうです。 当方の稚拙な質問に対して ご丁寧なアドバイスを
いただき、とても有り難いです。(^.^)
ゆっくりになりそうですが 解決できそうです。